# How to disable click but keep the overlay effects

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

In a Wordpress site, I need to disable the click from some thumbnails, keeping the overlay effects when mouse hover in the page http://srougi.biz/gb/produtos. I didn't find a way to do it.

Comment: This is not a CSS trick as far as I know, you will need to use Javascript to change this behaviour.

Comment: Im not so familiar with javascript. Could u tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript to disable onclick() event on your thumbnails and keep your effects onmouseover() event.

Read the following link: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470771

Let's suppose your thumbnails are images.
Following would be your html:

```
<img id="thumbnail" src="sourcefile.jpg" OnMouseOver="MouseOverEvent()" OnClick="return false;"/>
```

The following would be your javascript element (you can add it in the html file with a  tag)

```
<script>
function OnMouseOverEvent()
{
//you can set your effects here
}
</script>
```

Comment: I just readed that but I don't know how to set this in my site. Can u give me an example using my site elements?

Comment: I have editted my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently using jQuery on that page. Maybe this could work.

```
jQuery('div.thumbail > a').unbind('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the hrf from  tag

```
<a href="http://srougi.biz/gb/portfolio/acessorios/" title="Acessórios">
```

change to

```
<a title="Acessórios">
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you are unable to handle click events in CSS. If you wanted to disable clicks for all of the thumbnails, using jQuery(for simplicity), you could add this directly to the head of your site:

```
<script src="path/to/your/jquery.js"></script>

<script>

    (function($) {

        // find all 'a' elements inside of the 'thumbnail' class
        var block_click = $('.thumbnail').find('a'); 

        // function to create the new behavior you want to achieve
        function prevent_default_click_behavior(e) {

            // You can use this
            e.preventDefault();

            // Or this method
            return false;

        }

        // then, bind the desired behavior to the elements click event
        block_click.on('click', prevent_default_click_behavior);

    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

If you want to disable the link on some images, and leave it alone for others, you could use a different class to specify between the two. A simple implementation may look something like this:

```
<div class="thumbnail stop-click">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="src/to/image/jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

And now with the javascript, I can easily say "use my behavior" for all of my thumbnails with the 'stop-click' class.

```
<script>

    (function($) {

        // all 'a' elements inside the 'thumbnail' class that also has the 'stop-click' class
        var block_click = $('.thumbnail.stop-click').find('a'); 

        // function to create the new behavior you want to achieve
        function prevent_default_click_behavior(e) {

            // You can use this
            e.preventDefault();

            // Or this method
            return false;

        }    

        // then, bind the desired behavior to the elements click event
        block_click.on('click', prevent_default_click_behavior);

    })(jQuery);

</script>
```